# How come I need to pass variables this struct when I declare it in Swift?

Tags: xcode, function, swift, methods, struct

What am I doing wrong? 
I have a Class with a variable that is a struct and that works perfectly. However I also have a variable within the struct that is of type another struct. When I declare that variable (the second level struct) it keeps asking me to provide the variables.. I just want them blank and I will set them or send them values later.

#### ERROR TEXT:

Missing argument for parameter 'SV_StinkLocation_Longitude' in call

#### Calling Code:

```
struct SV_StinkDetails_Model{
    var SV_StinkDetails_Description:String = ""
    var SV_StinkDetails_RecordingDate:NSDate! = NSDate()
    var SV_StinkDetails_Location:SV_StinkLocation_Model! = SV_StinkLocation_Model()
}
```

#### ERROR LINE

```
var SV_StinkDetails_Location:SV_StinkLocation_Model! = SV_StinkLocation_Model()
```

#### Struct Code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData
import AVFoundation
import CoreLocation


struct SV_StinkLocation_Model{  
    var SV_StinkLocation_Longitude:NSNumber!
    var SV_StinkLocation_Latitude:NSNumber!
    var SV_StinkLocation_Suburb:String!
    var SV_StinkLocation_State:String!
    var SV_StinkLocation_Country:String!
}
```

However it works fine when I make the details struct a class variable.

```
var SV_Stink_StinkDetails:SV_StinkDetails_Model! = SV_StinkDetails_Model()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice to change your Model struct to:

```
struct SV_StinkDetails_Model{
    var SV_StinkDetails_Description:String
    var SV_StinkDetails_RecordingDate:NSDate
    var SV_StinkDetails_Location :SV_StinkLocation_Model?
}
```

You don’t have to declare values since you use the default init (neither do you need to declare them if you use a custom init)
In the struct I placed above your Location_Model is a optional, this means you can set the initial value to “nil”. Later you can add this info.
Remember to check (with a “if let” statement) if the value is set whenever you try to access it though!

For added value:
You don’t need to put the “!” behind your type declarations in the Model struct.

If you change these 2 things you can get your new class using:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData
import AVFoundation
import CoreLocation

struct SV_StinkLocation_Model{
    var SV_StinkLocation_Longitude:NSNumber
    var SV_StinkLocation_Latitude:NSNumber
    var SV_StinkLocation_Suburb:String
    var SV_StinkLocation_State:String
    var SV_StinkLocation_Country:String
}

struct SV_StinkDetails_Model{
    var SV_StinkDetails_Description:String
    var SV_StinkDetails_RecordingDate:NSDate
    var SV_StinkDetails_Location :SV_StinkLocation_Model?
}

var details_model = SV_StinkDetails_Model(SV_StinkDetails_Description: "Description:", SV_StinkDetails_RecordingDate: NSDate(), SV_StinkDetails_Location: nil)

details_model.SV_StinkDetails_Location = SV_StinkLocation_Model(SV_StinkLocation_Longitude: 1, SV_StinkLocation_Latitude: 1, SV_StinkLocation_Suburb: “Suburb", SV_StinkLocation_State: "State", SV_StinkLocation_Country: "Country")
```

Lastly you can access let’s say the longtitude of the option value using:

```
if let longtitude =  details_model.SV_StinkDetails_Location?.SV_StinkLocation_Longitude {
    println(longtitude)
}
```

Comment: Absolute Legend Thanks. I am still finding it hard to get my head around the Bloody Optional factor in Swift. Really appreciate you answer @milo526

Comment: How can I call the function in my Location Struct?

Comment: The if let statement could be used here ones more. You could check if a optioneel location has been set, if it has been set you can do all what you could do with a normal location struct (can't access my Mac atm, I'll upload an example this afternoon)

Comment: @TimHiatt Since comments aren’t the most pretty place to explain code; I’ve made a pastebin paste with code [here](http://pastebin.com/sQLjcZhY) I hope this will help you use your functions